# I can't get Live Unit Testing to see .runsettings

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying out "Live unit Testing" in VS2017, and ran into a problem. It looks like Live unit Testing doesn't pick up the settings in my .runsettings file.

When I'm in my code, my tests fail. Red cross next to the code, and red test in Test Explorer. But when I don't touch the code, and run the same tests from the Test Explorer, the tests go green (but still red cross next to code).

Am I missing something, is it not possible with .runsettings file, or is this a bug?

Additional info:

- I'm testing a C# class library (project and test project created with vs2015)
- I removed Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework from the test project
- I added MSTest.TestFramework 1.1.11
- and MSTest.TestAdapter 1.1.12 to the test project
- Using .NET Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Live Unit Testing only honors the test adapter path from the .runsettings file at this time. We are working to add support to honor other settings as well.

Comment: So, just to make it clear: SetAdaptersPaths is under the RunConfiguration element. Anything under TestRunParameters is not recognized at this time, but it will eventually be recognized, right?